# Best way to avoid this if else logic in partial? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a partial which is used all over the site. I have an image in the partial that I want to link to a certain page on all pages except one particular controller action.

**1.** Is there way to put in the following href without 2 if else sets?...

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="#" />
</a>
```

**I'm trying to avoid doing this:**

```
<% if (current controller != xyz) %>
  <a href="#">
<% end %>
   <img src="#" />
<% if (current controller != xyz) %>
  </a>
<% end %>
```

**2. How can I actually check which controller called this partial?**

The above code is only pseudo code.

**PS.** I know this isn't that much repetition, but I'm just using this simplified case as an example. Curious if there's something in Rails I don't know about to avoid this.

Comment: Why not make a separate partial just for the special controller's views?

Comment: @Emily's answer for 1.  For 2., just set a `@i_am_foo = true` in the offending controller action and then use that as your if condition in `link_to_if` - it should pass through on the other controllers/actions because `@i_am_foo` will be nil.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the `controller_name` method, which will return the name of the calling controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is exactly what [`link_to_if`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if) is for!

```
link_to_if(controller_name == 'xyz', image_tag('src'), 'http://target.com')
```

This will add the image whether the condition is true or not, and wrap it in the link only when the condition is true. There's also the related `link_to_unless` which may be more semantically appropriate in your case.

**Edit:** I've updated the example above to use the correct code for checking the controller name. There's a method available in the view, `controller_name` that returns a lowercase version of the name of your controller. It's also in the `params` hash.

Comment: Awesome! Rails never ceases to amaze.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to this question: "What do you want to duplicate".

In your question, you duplicate the if test.  In a counter example (below) I will duplicate the img tag.

Counter Example

```
<% if (current controller != xyz) %>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="#"/>
  </a>
<% end %>
<% if (current controller == xyz) %>
    <img src="#"/>
<% end %>
```

My preference is to duplicate the thing that is least likely to change and, when I don't know which is least likely to change, then default to the shortest amount of duplication.

Shortest is vague on purpose.  The image tag, as written, appears to be the shortest, but I suspect the if part will usually be the shortest.